# how to change Div based on another div

Tags: jquery

**my code like this:**

```
#border-content3
{
    margin: 15px auto;
    padding: 1%;    
    position: relative;             
    float: left;    
}
#right-menu
{
    min-width: 150px;   
    margin: 15px auto;
    padding: 1%;    
    position: relative;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 12px !important; 
    float: right;
}
```

**and Html Code like this:**

```
<div id="right-menu">

 </div>
<div id="border-content3">
<input name="test" class="test" id="test" value="a" type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

**i try to moving checkbox on right menu,but do not work this**

```
$('#test').css("position","absolute");
$('#test').css("z-index","3000"));
$('#test').animate({left:'400'},1000));
```

please help me for moving select element on right menu with jquery

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking, but try to add `px` to your animate: `$('#test').animate({left:'400px'},1000));`

Comment: item moving,but no display when moved to right menu

Comment: Try `$('#test').css("position","absolute");
$('#test').css("z-index","3000");
$('#test').animate({left:'400px'},1000);`

Comment: do not work ,element moved,but not display,element moved behind of right menu

Comment: Can you show more HTML / CSS? There must be something else going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 typos in your code. 2 extra `)`, and a missing `px`

```
$('#test').css("position","absolute");

$('#test').css("z-index","3000") **)** ;

$('#test').animate({left:'400 **px** '},1000) **)** ;
```

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/GCGWv/3/

(tried on FF, Chrome, IE 10, safari 5)